# specify DeployIisAppPath for asp.net application deployment

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an asp.net framework web application on AWS beanstalk. After deployment, i had the following error: Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST More Information: Site '.' does not exist.

I understood That this means that a DeployIisAppPath property group must be set. I created a pubxml file inside Properties/PublishProfiles folder , containing that parameter. 
  But it seems like it was ignored because i had the same error . Any idea please ?

Comment: Have you deployed the web application by following this link? It sounds like you didn't create host environment correctly.